# Set value from database to JavaScript using php

Tags: javascript, php, database, google-maps, mysqli

I have to show google map marker in my website where the value of latitude and longitude is coming from database from `latitude` and `longitude` columns.

Initially JavaScript code is

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    map = new GMaps({
        div: '#map',
        lat: -37.817917,
        lng: 144.965065,
        zoom: 16

    });
    map.addMarker({
        lat: -37.81792,
        lng: 144.96506,
        title: 'Marker with InfoWindow',
        icon: 'images/map-marker.png',
        infoWindow: {
            content: '<p>Melbourne Victoria, 300, Australia</p>'
        }
    });
}
```

I tried with placing php code as:

```
lat: <?php echo $latitude; ?>
lng: <?php echo $latitude; ?>
```

But it doesn't work.

I figure out one more way to do this is set input field value to the coordinates and then call it to JavaScript using `getElementById`

```
<input id="map_latitude" value="<?= $latitude ?>" hidden>
<input id="map_longitude" value="<?= $longitude ?>" hidden>
```

and in JavaScript: *(this is just experimental, don't know whether correct or not)*

```
lat: getElementById('#map_latitude'),
lng: getElementById('#map_longitude')
```

Comment: The second part should works. Try to make `lat:  $('#map_latitude').val(),
lng: .$(#map_longitude').val()`. If you set JQuery. PS : make sure that you're not getting empty values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should totally work:

```
div: '#map',
lat: <?php echo $latitude; ?>,
lng: <?php echo $longitude; ?>,
```

The second option should work too but with a little change.

```
var map;
var lati = getElementById('map_latitude').value;   //Need to select the value
var longi = getElementById('map_longitude').value; //and remove the hashtag ( # )
function initialize() {
    map = new GMaps({
        div: '#map',
        lat: lati,
        lng: longi,
        zoom: 16
```

Always check your console for errors.

Answer (score 2):

For second option try the below

```
lat: document.getElementById('map_latitude').value,
lng: document.getElementById('map_longitude').value
```